# Angular - Could not find a declaration file for module 'file-saver'

Tags: angular, file-saver

In my Angular-12 project I installed file-saver:

```
npm install file-saver@2.0.5

npm install --save exceljs

ng generate service services/export-excel
```

Then in the export-excel service, I added:

```
import * as fs from 'file-saver';
```

I got **file-saver** highlighted

with this error:

> Could not find a declaration file for module 'file-saver'. 'c:/xampp/htdocs/myapp/node_modules/file-saver/dist/FileSaver.min.js' implicitly has an 'any' type.
> Try `npm i --save-dev @types/file-saver` if it exists or add a new declaration (.d.ts) file containing `declare module 'file-saver';`

But I didn't use:

> @types/file-saver

How do I get this error resolved?

Thanks

Comment: @types/file-saver is used by for tslint of typesctipt itself. so it is better to install it when installing a library. So you can now just try `npm i --save-dev @types/file-saver`

Comment: @VishnuVinod - So, it means I will now have two (2) file-saver

Comment: Not like that. The `@types/file-saver` is like an optional dependency for `file-saver` when it is using with typescript. so you wll get code suggestions and and auto-completions from `file-saver` library

Answer (score 13):

## Additional typescript definitions

npm install @types/file-saver --save-dev

Answer (score 8):

I just solved a similar error with the same error message (I am working currently in a Angular 13 proyect), there is a solution first you will have to create a folder called 'types' in the same folder level of src:

[image: create 'types' folder in the same level of src]

then inside that folder create another folder with your module name 'file-saver' in this case and inside there a file called 'index.d.ts'

The final result need to look something like:

[image]

Last step is to put inside index.d.ts the following code:

```
declare module 'file-saver';
```

Comment: Works in Angular 15 too.

Answer (score 0):

Add

> "file-saver": "~2.0.5"

to the dependencies section in the package.json file, and remove it from the devDependencies section.